# How will I take Köppen-Geiger Climate regions into account when running a multivariate regression analysis?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I am doing an analysis on the efficiency of solar plants and naturally, one of the factors I want to take into account is the climate that the plant is in. I am using the Köppen-Geiger classification system. So a data point would be (BSk) for example. How can I use this data in a multivariate regression analysis?

I am thinking running a different regression for each category and comparing them. I am hoping there is a more simple way.